# How to calculate in linux number of file inside nested directories?

Tags: linux, files, bash, scripting, directory

I need to extract information how much files are in some directory tree:

```
  /.../testRoot/test1/test11/..../file1
  /.../testRoot/test1/test11/file2
  /.../testRoot/test1/test11/..../file3
  /.../testRoot/test1/test11/file4
.....................................
  /.../testRoot/test1/test1n/fileq
  /.../testRoot/test1/test1n/..../filew
  /.../testRoot/test1/test1n/filee
  /.../testRoot/test1/test1n/.../.../ .../filer
```

How to calculate how many files are inside of testRoot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`find /path/to/testRoot -type f | wc -l`

Comment: This will break for files with newlines in the name.

Comment: And also won't count symlinks, sockets, device specials, and anything other than plain ole boring files. Which is okay in many cases. If files with newlines are an issue, you can try `find /path/to/testRoot -type f | awk -v RS='\0' '{n++} END {print n}'`

Comment: If you want all those non-bording files to the point where you are looking for everything but directories, then `find -not -type d` can help.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash4` and above:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
i=0
for f in /path/to/testRoot/*/**; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && (( i++ ))
done
echo "$i"
```